# Asymptotic estimation for binomial variables

Tags: asymptotics, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

I am trying to understand the mathematical aspects of a Galton board with (as) "elementary" (as possible) tools.

I had the idea that the gaussian shape which appears with the board can be explained by the convergence in distribution of a normalized sum of binomial variables to a $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ variable (CLT). Am I right (especially for the type of convergence) ?

For the mathematical aspect : let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ $n$ random independent variables with the same distribution $\mathcal{B}(n,p)$ where $0<p<1$. If $x\in\mathbb{R}$, the CLT implies $\displaystyle\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{S_n-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\leq x\right)\underset{{n}\longrightarrow{+\infty}}\longrightarrow\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{t^2}2}\mathrm{d}t$. I would like to prove this limit by "elementary" means (Stirling approximation, integral representations and dominated convergence for example).

I suppose that $p=\frac 12$ for simplicity. We have to prove $\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor np+x\sqrt{np(1-p)}\rfloor}\mathbb{P}\left(S_n=j\right)=\frac 1{2^n}\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n+x\sqrt n}2\rfloor}\binom{n}{j}\underset{{n}\longrightarrow{+\infty}}\longrightarrow\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{t^2}2}\mathrm{d}t$.

It can be shown that $\displaystyle\sum_{j=k}^n\binom njp^j(1-p)^{n-j}=k\binom nk\int_0^pt^{k-1}(1-t)^{n-k}\mathrm{d}t$.

My second question is : how can I find the limit of $\displaystyle k\binom nk\int_0^{\frac 12}t^{k-1}(1-t)^{n-k}\mathrm{d}t$ as $n\longrightarrow +\infty$, where $k=\lfloor\frac{n+x\sqrt n}2\rfloor+1$ ? Pearhaps the Laplace method could conclude, but I don't find a good change of variable and would like to apply dominated convergence theorem... Thank you.

Comment: Your special case of the CLT is also known as the *De Moivre–Laplace Theorem*, so I will just note that you may also be interested in looking up that Theorem to find many elementary proofs :)

Comment: Thank you Maximilian...I must admit that I had forgotten this special case. With the integral form, I thought however that it was not so hard to conclude directly after a good change of variable.

Comment: Notice that you are interested in $n\to \infty$, but not with $k$ constant, rather with $k/n =x$ constant (that is, $k \to \infty$ too).